# Update a software that has been downloaded with an apple ID associated with a deleted email address

Tags: email, mac-appstore, xcode, apple-id, software-update

I am trying to update XCode. When I go on the AppStore and try to update XCode I receive the following message:

```
You have updates available for other accounts

Sign in to <email.address@PastUniv.com> to update applications for that account.
```

email.address@PastUniv.com is an address email I had in my previous university and this email address has now been canceled!

How can I update XCode with the Apple ID I am using today?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have any user data stored within the xCode.app file structure, just delete the xCode app.  Then re-download it from the AppStore using your new AppleID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I search for Xcode on AppStore I only have the opportunity to update and not to re-download it. Should I first uninstall my XCode to be able to re-download it?

Comment: Yes.  Just make sure you saved your projects outside of the xCode.app folder.  By default they are saved to your user folder.

Comment: Ok. And now I realize that the new version is not available on my OS version. Wel... I guess there's nothing further to do but buying the new OS version, right?